# Upload package without source to pypi repo

Tags: python, egg, pypi

Apologies if this has been asked before but I couldn't for the life of me find an answer to what seems (to me) like a very basic question.

I have a set of .egg packages that do not contain the source (e.g. there is no setup.py file). I need to register and upload these packages to our inhouse pypi repository. Is there any way to do this, short of manually copying the package into the pypi repository directory and manually inserting the entries into the pypi db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to manually register these.

You can, however, use the PyPI web interface to do this. The central PyPI server has a `Package submission` link in the left-hand menu bar, leading to `http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=submit_form`, presumably your local installation has the same.

Your `.egg`s are either directories, or zip files. If it is not a directory, you need to unzip the file to look inside (create a copy that you rename to have a `.zip` extension if that'll make it easier for your tools to recognize it as a zip file).

You'll find a `EGG-INFO` subdirectory inside the egg, and inside of that you'll find a `PKG-INFO` file. You can upload this file to the package submission form to replace the `setup.py register` command.

Once registered, the web UI lets you navigate to the package, from there to the `files` section of a specific package and upload the egg file.

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to store the package on an **inhouse** repository, and not the official pypi server.

Comment: @B.W.Baugh: It's the same software. I am using the official PyPI server as an illustration; there is not enough context to be *100%* certain the OP's internal server will have the same UI (depends on version, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Welp, I tried upload the package as you described...It is embarrassing to admit but actually I was being stupid and didn't realize that our inhouse pypi repo runs on ClueReleaseManager, not the official pypi implementation.

Comment: @SleepingPills: Ah; that makes things different of course. There is a command line utility for that server, and a quick glance does make it appear that the `adddistro` subcommand will take an egg to register it's PKG-INFO file (see https://github.com/serverzen/ClueReleaseManager/blob/master/src/clue/relmgr/cmdtool.py#L187).